# unable to open pdf file in django

Tags: python, html, django, pdf

my file directory is :

```
site
-search
 -factfinder
  -pdf_reports
    test.pdf
```

in my base.html file, i have :

```
<a class="linkbtn" href='/factfinder/pdf_reports/{{ab.0.file_name}}.pdf' >open pdf</a>
```

but on clicking the link, i get redirected to http://localhost:8000/factfinder/pdf_reports/test.pdf and i get an error stating page not found.

i also get following details to error :

```
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
elasticsearch_results/ [name='elasticsearch_results']
pdf_open [name='pdf_open']
pdf_open_2 [name='pdf_open_2']
rating [name='rating']
parse_pdf [name='parse_pdf']
filters [name='filters']
run_model [name='run_model']
The current path, factfinder/pdf_reports/test.pdf, didn't match any of these.
```

Comment: What do you mean by file directory? Do you mean *media* dir? Why there is no search dir before factfinder dir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a media folder and create factfinder/pdf_reports folders in media folder and save test.pdf file in that.
and then add

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

in setting.py file (end of file)
and add following code in urls.py file

```
    from django.conf import settings
    urlpatterns = [
         ....(your urls)
         ....
    ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I hope it works